# Datastore Admin 500 Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I enabled datastore admin from the google cloud console. After clicking 'Open datastore admin' I get the following result:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

I use a custom domain, but don't use Google Apps for work. I have found other people with the same problem, suggesting it would depend on the authentication type being set to 'federated login', which should be 'Google Accounts Api', I have found no such setting in the Google Cloud console.

What should I do to access the datastore admin?

Comment: Maybe monitor it for a while and see if this problem persists, since it is a server error. You can also try uploading some entities first.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? It may have been a transient issue while the admin package was going deployed.

Comment: Hi Dan, I just checked and the problem was solved. I you are right, the project was just created when I had the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My GCP project was newly created when this problem arose. After a short time the datastore admin now works as it should.